# Accessing a function with both string and numbers?

Tags: javascript

I need to modify the below code in a way that I can access the averageString -function with a string as well as the numbers. I also need to modify the return statement, but I don't know how to refer to the string 'age' in the return statement, so here it is represented by (X).

What I have now:

```
function averageString(...numbers) {
    let sum = 0;
    numbers.forEach(function (x) {
        sum += x;
    });
    return The average of (X) is sum / numbers.length;
}

console.log(averageString('age', 12, 15, 20))
```

Console output should read: The average of 'Age' is 15.666666666666666

Comment: `return The average of (X) is sum / numbers.length;` is clearly a syntax error

Comment: I think that's intentional pseudocode as a placeholder for the desired syntax. OP, why not use the header `averageString(label, numbers)`? Using the varargs syntax seems less intuitive than just passing in an array of numbers. Even here, I don't see that a `label` parameter belongs--better that the average logic operates only on numbers and doesn't do any string formatting, for maximum reusability.

Comment: So remove the first index

Comment: Please do not put the solution in the question; I have rolled back your latest edit. If you want to answer your own question to provide the solution, you may do so.

Answer (score 1):

So define the first argument as another variable and use the spread for the remaining values.

```js
function averageString(str, ...numbers) {
    let sum = 0;
    numbers.forEach(function (x) {
        sum += x;
    });
    return `The average of ${str} is ${sum / numbers.length}`
}

console.log(averageString('age', 12, 15, 20))
console.log(averageString('foo', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what the purpose of passing the string is, but you can pass the numbers in an array and your function should work.

```
function averageString(myStr, numbers) {
    let sum = 0;
    numbers.forEach(function (x) {
        sum += x;
    });
    return 'The average of ' + myStr + ' is ' + (sum / numbers.length);
}

console.log(averageString('age', [12, 15, 20]));
```

Comment: You can do the same thing with spread variables, just do `(myStr, ...numbers)` instead. For me it's just a matter of clarity in this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an array for your number variable.

```
function averageString(name,numbers) {
    let sum = 0;
    numbers.forEach(function (x) {
        sum += x;
    });
    return 'The average of (' + name + ')  is ' + sum / numbers.length;
}

document.getElementById("returnVal").innerHTML = averageString('age',[12, 15, 20])
```

https://jsfiddle.net/31j5p7zf/

Comment: Why use an array over an optional amount of parameters like OP had it originally? epascarello does it in his answer

Comment: @chevybow There isn't really a difference, only thing is if OP was using this function to plug something into the parameters. Ex: averageString('fooString',fooArray), it is easier to do that instead of inputting a massive list of strings